# Can QGIS export a limited area of a project?

Tags: qgis, extents, extract

I am new to GIS in general, and I've created a map in QGIS that contains data for a very large area.

I would like to copy this onto a mobile device, but the file size is too large, and I don't need the whole map area anyway.  I am trying to work out whether I can export the QGIS project, as another QGIS project, but with each layer limited to a specific area (e.g. what is shown on the screen when performing the export).

I have worked out how to do this on a per-layer basis by exporting and setting extents, but I have around 30 layers so it will be difficult to export and re-import each of these one by one.  And then I will have to repeat that process each time I update the map.

Is there a way to tell QGIS to do this automatically, so that I can bundle the whole project together into a single file, with only data included in each layer for the area I am interested in?

I'd like to keep the output file as a QGIS project as the app I am trying out - "QField for QGIS" seems to have the most functionality when reading in a QGIS project.

Comment: Do you have vector or raster data? Or both?

Comment: Both, although the raster data is less useful in the field so I could live without that if need be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will clip all vector layers by map extent and store in one geopackage and all rasters as individual tif files. Try it on a subset of layers first.

```py
import os
output_folder = r"C:\TEMP\Ny mapp"
output_gpkg = "vector_layers.gpkg"

map_extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent() #Calculate current map extent
layer_tree_root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot() #For checking layer visibility

clipped_vectors = [] #A list to hold clipped vector layers
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For every layer added to the map
    if layer_tree_root.findLayer(layer).isVisible(): #If the layer is visible/checked
        if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer): #If it is a vector layer
            print(f"Clipping vectorlayer: {layer.name()}")
            vl = processing.run("native:extractbyextent", #Clip using extract by extent, and append layer to list
                {'INPUT':layer,'EXTENT':map_extent,'CLIP':True,
                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]
            vl.setName(layer.name())
            clipped_vectors.append(vl)

        elif isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer): #If it is a raster layer
            print(f"Clipping rasterlayer: {layer.name()}")
            processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbyextent",  #Clip using another tool and save the output as a tif
                {'INPUT':layer,'PROJWIN':map_extent,'OVERCRS':False,
                'NODATA':None,'OPTIONS':'COMPRESS=LZW','DATA_TYPE':0,
                'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':os.path.join(output_folder, f"{layer.name()}_clip.tif")})
        
#Package all clipped vector layers to a geopackage
processing.run("native:package", {'LAYERS':clipped_vectors,
    'OUTPUT':os.path.join(output_folder, output_gpkg),
    'OVERWRITE':False,'SAVE_STYLES':True,'SAVE_METADATA':True,
    'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY':False,'EXPORT_RELATED_LAYERS':False})

print("Done")
```

Comment: Nice!  Is there any way to make it skip hidden layers?  It seems to struggle a bit trying to download some of the online layers, which I have already downloaded as other layers and thus hidden.  I get a lot of errors when running the script I will have to investigate, but it does produce an output file.  I can't work out how to open the output file either (nothing happens when I try to "open project from GeoPackage") but I will continue experimenting and see if I can work it out!  Many thanks!

Comment: I've added a check if the layer is visible/checked or not. It doesnt export the project to a geopackage, just the layers. You need to create a new qgz project with the new layers, or change the layer sources in the current project to the clipped layers.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thanks!  That got rid of the errors and I can successfully add it to a new project.  It seems to lose all the styles though, but I guess if I copy them across manually, they should remain even as I keep exporting the project over the top of the same geopackage file?

Comment: Also it seems to skip raster layers with the error `CRITICAL ERROR 1: Error: Computed -srcwin -3.38467e+07 -6.33023e+06 0 0 has negative width and/or height.`

Comment: Do your map have different coordinate system compared to some of the layers that cant be exported?

Comment: Oh yes they do, all the vector layers are GDA2020 or GDA94 but all the raster ones are WGS84.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [Räumlicher Filter](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spatial_filter/) which provides spatial filtering fitting this exact use case.

[image]

- https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spatial_filter/
- https://github.com/WhereGroup/spatial_filter